# filter js/nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

Мне нужно вывести список пользователей и чтобы в этом списке были все кроме на данный момент авторизованного пользователя. Предполагаю, что нужно использовать метод filter, но никак не могу разобраться как. Вот, что есть на данный момент.

```js
exports.users = async (req, res) => {
    if(!req.user) {
        return res.redirect('/login')
    }
    const myId = req.user.id;
    const users = await userModel.getAll();

    return res.render('users', { users: users });
}
```

Comment: тут нужен не метод `filter`, а аргумент в выборку данных: `const users = await userModel.getAll({ where: { Id: { not_in: [CURRENT_USER_ID] } } })` // _пример приведён псевдокодом_

Answer (score 0):

Думаю как-то так

```
const filteredUsers = users.filter(item=>item.id != myId);
```

Comment: Я бы, наверное, сначала нашел индекс юзера, а потом бы вырезал с помощью splice. Для оптимизации